# No passkey icon option on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, office365, yubikey, fido2

I am trying to enable passkey login on Windows 10 devices.

I have enabled UseSecurityKeyForSignin and EnableFIDODeviceLogon as well as enabled WHfB in gpedit.msc According to RSOP, passkey login is enabled, WHfB is enabled, yet the logon page does now show any options besides passwords.

I also enabled the policies in intune (./Device/Vendor/MSFT/PassportForWork/SecurityKey/UseSecurityKeyForSignin) and synced it down, still no passkey option.

When I go to Sign in Settings -> Security Key, it detects my security key information from 365 and asks to reset or manage PIN, but I simply have no login option for security keys.